# Flash "sketch" hex over ISP, without bootloader - possible?

Tags: bootloader, avrdude, isp

I'm wondering if it's possible to flash the arduino sketch into a AVR, without using a bootloader - over ISP. I'd use the BSD programmer, which is basically parallel port with some resistors.

Let's say I use the Arduino IDE, try to upload with "verbose" (no actual arduino is attached) - it shows path to the hex in the verbose output, and I "steal" the file.

Now I'd flash it using avrdude onto a blank 328 via ISP - would that work?

I assume there needs to be a 16Mhz crystal, is that it? Any other pitfalls I have to be careful about?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the arduino bootloader on the chip, if you are programming it using ISP.

It looks like BSD is no longer supported by avrdude.

In the Arduino 1.5 IDE you can add programmers, so you can do the uploading right from the IDE, instead of 'stealing' the hex file and manually uploading from the command line.

If the chips are blank you probably need to change the fuses first.

You don't need a 16mhz crystal. The atmega328 has an internal 8mHz oscillator inside.

Comment: Avrdude seems to support BSD just fine, look: `bsd              = Brian Dean's Programmer, http://www.bsdhome.com/avrdude/` in the programmers list. The link is dead though, but there's schematics on google.

Comment: `-c bsd` doesn't work on my 2 versions of avrdude. But that might be because I'm on a Mac. So Windows might work fine.

Comment: Macs don't usually have a parallel port, so it's not surprising that a parallel port programmer isn't supported on it.

Comment: Edited to mention that using the internal oscillator means you can't use the UART reliably ( you can calibrate it but if the temperature changes it will be wrong again)

Comment: @cb88 I think that only applies to the higher baud-rates. Also, please add this information as a comment, instead of an edit. I don't think such an edit is appropriate.

Comment: Probably if you have ideal code setting up the baud rates... but it certainly isn't foolproof and the Arduino guys are known for getting those not quite right.... I think their code there is a bit better these days but it's still a likely source of headaches. And they acutally had *more* issues at low baud rates.